A question about G-Hewitt spaces
In the paper linked below, S. A. Antonyan gives the following proposition without proof (in fact all results are given without proof). I need a proof of this theorem. If anyone has information on this subject, can you comment?
Propoition 7: A $G$-space is compact if and only if it is simultaneously $G$-pseudocompact
(it is equivalent $\beta _{G}X=\beta X$, as mentioned in the article) and $G$-Hewitt.
$G$-pseudocompact and $G$-Hewitt spaces

At least for me, your link does not download a paper, but rather directs me to the mathnet.ru home page (I suppose that's what it is—it's in Russian, understandably—but it certainly doesn't seem to be a particular paper).  Could you give the title of the paper?

@LSpice I edited. It should be working now

Re, yes, thanks, the link now works for me; but I think that it is still helpful to know the title "$G$-pseudocompact and $G$-Hewitt spaces", so I edited it in (and changed the link to the hopefully more robust DOI while I was at it).

The statement is analogous to the general result that, for Tychonoff spaces, compactness is equivalent to pseudo-compactness plus realcompactness, see the beginning of section 3.11 in Engelking's General Topology. Antonyan's definition of $G$-Hewitt is the equivariant version of the definition of realcompactness used by Engelking. And the result you are asking about is the equivariant analogue of Theorem 3.11.1. It is clear that compactness implies $G$-pseudocompactness and $G$-Hewittness. For the converse: if $X$ is $G$-pseudocompact then $\beta X$ is an extension that satisfies (b) in Antonyan's definition 2, if $X$ is also $G$-Hewitt then (a) must fail, so $X=\beta X$.

First of all, thank you very much for your reply. I would like to ask another question about this.

I want to define $G$-realcompactification as follows. Let $X$ be a Tychonoff
space. We will call a realcompact $G$-space $R$ as $G$-reelcompactification
of $X$ satisfying the following conditions.



$R$ contains $X$ as a dense invariant subspace.


For each $G$-equivariant map $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ into a realcompact $G$-space $Y$ can be equivariantly  extended to $\overline{f}:R\longrightarrow Y
$.



We will denote the maximal $G$-realcompactification of $X$ by $\upsilon _{G}X
$. If $\upsilon _{G}X=X$, then $X$ will be called $G$-Hewitt.
My definition should not be different from Antonyan's definition (if I am not mistaken). Based on this definition, how can we say that $X$ is compact if $\beta _{G}X=\beta X$ and $X=\upsilon _{G}X$?

@MehmetOnat In the general case $\upsilon X$ sits between $X$ and $\beta X$; so you should establish that this also holds in the equivariant case. If $X$ is $G$-pseudocompact then so is $\upsilon_GX$ and as the latter is $G$-Hewitt you would be able to conclude $\upsilon_GX=\beta_GX$.

Do you think that my definition may not require $X\subset \upsilon _{G}X\subset \beta _{G}X$ ?. My second question: if $\upsilon _{G}X$ is $G$-pseudocompact and $\upsilon _{G}X$ is $G$-Hewitt, why $\upsilon _{G}X=\beta _{G}X$?

Your definition may not require it but I think you can prove that you can identify $\upsilon_GX$ as a space between $X$ and $\beta_GX$: in Engelking's book $\upsilon X$ is constructed (Theorem 3.11.10) as a subspace of $\beta X$. Once you have done that my previous comment applies. And in that case $\upsilon_GX=\beta_GX$ because $\beta_G(\upsilon_GX)=\beta(\upsilon_GX)$ (as $\upsilon_G(X)$ is $G$-pseudocompact, because $X$ is) and because $X\subseteq\upsilon_GX\subseteq\beta X$ we have $\beta(\upsilon_GX)=\beta X=\beta_GX$. No apply the last sentence of my answer.

I think only $\beta _{G}\left( \upsilon _{G}X\right) =\beta \left( \upsilon _{G}X\right)=\beta X=\beta _{G}X$ equations do not imply that $\upsilon _{G}X=\beta _{G}X$. It seems that other arguments are needed for this. Further, I think Antonyan's definition is more restrictive than mine. The reason why you can apply $\beta X$ to (b) in Antonyan's definition 2 is that $\varphi $ is a continuous equivariant and bounded mapping.

I think $\beta X$ does not apply to condition 2 in my definition because it is not bounded. Perhaps there is a reason why Antonyan used the bounded and continuous $\varphi :X\longrightarrow C\left( G\right) $ instead of the 2 condition in my definition. I don't quite understand why he would do such a thing instead of the equivariant version of Engelking's classical definition 3.11.

This is the case (c) of Theorem 4 in Antonyan's article. In a previous correspondence with Antonyan I asked him if condition (b) of Theorem 4 could be removed and he said that it could.

To summarize, I don't understand why the maximal equivariant compactification $\beta_G X$ is defined by the equivariant version of the usual Stone-Čech compactification, while the $G$-Hewitt realcompactification is defined using $C(G)$ and the concept of bounded function $\varphi :X\longrightarrow C\left( G\right) $.

I recommend this paper by Jan de Vries, G-spaces: compactifications and pseudocompactness. The first part surveys methods of obtaining G-compactifications. The idea is to replace $\mathbb{R}$ by the space $C(G)$. When building $\beta_GX$ you use continuous functions $f:X\to C(G)$ whose image has compact closure. For building $\upsilon_GX$ you need a metric co-domain, so you look at the bounded functions only (finite distance from the zero-function); if you follow the product construction you do not necessarily get a compact closure.

I have already looked at the article you mentioned and I will read it more carefully. But unfortunately I still cannot see why $\beta _{G}\left( \upsilon _{G}X\right) =\beta \left( \upsilon _{G}X\right)
=\beta X=\beta _{G}X$ implies $\upsilon _{G}X=\beta _{G}X$

We were working under the assumption that $X$ is $G$-pseudocompact, so if $f:X\to C(G)$ is equivariant and continuous then $f[X]$ has compact closure; because $X$ is dense in $\upsilon_GX$ the latter has this property too, so all (bounded) equivariant continuous maps from $\upsilon_GX$ can be extended to $\beta_GX$, that is, we have condition (b), because $\upsilon_GX$ is $G$-Hewitt condition (a) must fail, so $\upsilon_GX=\beta_GX$.

Thank you very much for your time and patience.
